# How to run heroku-buildpack-nginx locally in a docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, heroku, buildpack

I am trying to run this buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx locally in a docker container following the tutorial.

When I try to execute the second command after make shell I get this error:

```
$ make shell
$ cp bin/nginx-$STACK bin/nginx
$ FORCE=1 bin/start-nginx

cp: cannot stat 'bin/nginx-heroku-18': No such file or directory
```

I want to be able to start nginx buildpack to test it locally, but I am stuck at this error. Could someone help me please ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use it with the `pack` CLI by following this tutorial on [Using Heroku Buildpacks with Pack](http://jkutner.github.io/2020/05/26/cloud-native-buildpacks-shim.html)

Pack uses a newer version of the buildpack API, but the tutorial describes how to use an old buildpack with a shim so that it works.